# Adding multiple text to a figure

Tags: floats

I want to add a title and a text to figure in LaTex. I want to do is like this:
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{title}
\centering
\includegraphics{JonesTertilt.png}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
```

If I use `\caption` twice, It makes two different references to the figure.

Comment: just use any kind of paragraph text inside the figure it doesn't have to be in `\caption` (and don't use `[h!]` !!:-)

Comment: Welcome to the site. How did you obtain that figure? If you have used `pgfplots` then the `title` can be added there itself.

Comment: Each `\caption` increases the figure counter here and shows the line `Figure X.Y...` (unless configured otherwise with the `caption` package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told by David, you can put any content inside the `figure` environment, it need not be only `\caption` and `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
   \caption{title}\label{fig:mypic}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}
   %\caption*{text}

   \lipsum*[1]   %% leave an empty line above so that 'text' comes to next line
\end{figure} 

\ref{fig:mypic} is the picture
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you can load `\caption` package and use its `\caption*` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
   \caption{title}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption*{\lipsum*[1]}  \label{fig:mypic} 
\end{figure} 
Figure~\ref{fig:mypic} is the picture
\end{document}
```

[image]